# Norm Space verification

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

For each of the following decide whether the suggested formula defines a norm on the indicated space. You may assume that $||f||_1=\int_0^1 |f(t)| dt$ does give a norm on the space of all continuous functions on the interval $[0,1]$

$$V_a=\mathbb{R}^2 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  ||(x,y)||_a=|x+y|$$

$$V_b=\mathbb{R}^2 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  ||(x,y)||_b=max(|x|,|y|)$$

$$V_c=\mathbb{R}^2 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  ||(x,y)||_c=\int_0^1|x+yt|dt$$

$$V_d \ \ \ \ \ \ \ ||f||_d=\int_0^1|f'(t)|dt$$ where $V_d$ is the space of all differentiable functions $f$ on $[0,1]$ with $f'$ continuous.

The first 2 ($V_a$ and $V_b$) I know are norm spaces. The 3rd one $V_c$, the $t$ variable makes me nervous. Not sure how to work around it. But I ended up getting that it does satisfy all norm space properties. $V_d$ is not a norm space because if $f$ is constant, it would fail separates points axiom. Can anyone concur? Thank you.

Comment: I guess there is an error in the fourth one.

Comment: @E.T. Oops sorry I edited.

Comment: The fist one is not a norm. Note that $||(x,-x)||_a=|x+(-x)|=0,$ for any $x\in \mathbb{R}.$

Comment: $V_a$ is not a normed space, the line $x+y=0$ lies in the null-space of that "norm".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$V_c$ (which is apparantly the only one which is a problem for you) is a normed space, notice that if
$$\int_0^1|x+ty|dt=0$$
then it follows (since you may assume the standard norm on $C^0[0,1]$) that $|x+ty|=0$ for all $t\in[0,1]$, hence $(x,y)=(0,0)$. Can you do the triangle inequality?

Comment: I think so. I I just assumed for some $||(a,b)||$ $\int_0^1|x+yt+a+bt|dt \le \int_0^1|x+yt|dt+\int_0^1|a+bt|dt$

Comment: very true, this suffices.

Comment: What about the error on the 4th one?

Comment: well its just not clear what you mean by that norm, I mean is $f$ fixed?

Comment: $V_d$ is the space of all differentiable functions $f$ on [0,1] with $f′$ continuous. That's all I'm given.

Comment: In that case you should change notation isn't it? I mean the norm should be written $||f||=...$?

Comment: yes sorry fixed super thanks for that. Now is my argument valid?

Comment: @User69127: yeah it confused me for a minute or so. Yes it is! By the way your space $V_d$ is usually denoted $C^1[0,1]$.